# Scaling a tikzpicture generated with matlab2tikz

Tags: graphics, input, scaling, size, matlab2tikz

I have a figure `Plot1.tex` generated with matlab2tikz [(matlab2tikz by Nico Schlömer)](https://www.github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz). I want to include it in my document and scale its width and height like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 

% Recommended settings according to matlab2tikz:
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \setlength\figureheight{7.0cm}
    \setlength\figurewidth{5.0cm}
    \input{Plot1.tex}
    \caption{Figure 1 caption.}
    \label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However, the figure size is unaffected by the values I am specifiying in centimeters. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.
Solutions including `\textwidth` instead of a fixed length are also appreciated. I have tried that as well, but no luck either.

Edit: The contents of the file `Plot1.tex` look like this.

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
%
%The latest updates can be retrieved from
%  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz
%where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
%
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=4.521in,
height=3.566in,
at={(0.758in,0.481in)},
scale only axis,
bar width=0.8,
xmin=-0.2,
xmax=8.2,
xtick={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
xlabel={Case},
ymin=0,
ymax=4500,
ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
ylabel={Amount},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
]
\addplot[ybar stacked, fill=mycolor1, draw=black, area legend] table[row sep=crcr] {%
1   3364.193\\
2   2593.019\\
3   2636.492\\
4   2691.691\\
5   2792.946\\
6   2962.925\\
7   3109.8\\
};
\addplot[forget plot, color=white!15!black] table[row sep=crcr] {%
-0.2    0\\
8.2 0\\
};
\addlegendentry{Part 1}

\addplot[ybar stacked, fill=mycolor2, draw=black, area legend] table[row sep=crcr] {%
1   704.461\\
2   1275.311\\
3   1251.84\\
4   1196.23\\
5   1108.538\\
6   983.136\\
7   891.978\\
};
\addplot[forget plot, color=white!15!black] table[row sep=crcr] {%
-0.2    0\\
8.2 0\\
};
\addlegendentry{Part 2}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Comment: I am rather new to LaTeX and this may be a stupid question. I have been looking for similar questions, but haven't found one. If the same question does exist already, please refer to it and delete this post.

Comment: Since `matlab` is a commercial program not everyone have access to, it might be an idea to also add `Plot1.tex`, I don't even think `\input` is relevant here, you can just replace `\input{Plot1.tex}` by the contents of `Plot1.tex`, then it will be easier for others to help.

Comment: @daleif: Thank you. I added the contents of `Plot1.tex` to the question.

Comment: Note you might want to change the title to something more appropriate.

Comment: The width/height seems hardcoded into the generated code. You might want to look up how to configure `matlab2tikz` to use the `\figurexxx`  lengths you mentioned.

Comment: It **does** work if you manually change the `width=...` and `height=...` to `width=\figurewidth,` etc, but that is a bit hard when it is generated code. BTW when the figure is that simple, why are you doing it in MatLab to start with?

Comment: You were right. `matlab2tikz` does have an option to define height and width of a figure. It even relies on input regarding size. Otherwise it just 'assumes a reasonable size'. You can even specify relative sizes like `0.8\textwidth`. Very nice!
I remember doing it without explicitly specifying a size several years ago, but appearantly this has changed meanwhile. Thank you @daleif for helping me out with this one!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105663/discussion-between-dave-and-daleif).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to prescribe diagram size with ˙pgfplotsAssuming, that your image `Plot1.tex` is drawn by use of `pgfplots` package and that have not defined image size locally, than you can define size image size by inserting

```
\pgfplotsset{height=5.0cm,width=7.0cm}
```

before `\input{Plot1.tex}`.

In the case, that you draw this image by using `standalone` document file name `Plot1.tex`, that it my help you the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{standalone} % <---
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% Recommended settings according to matlab2tikz:
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,
             plot coordinates/math parser=false}
% \newlength\figureheight  % not needed
% \newlength\figurewidth   % not needed

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\pgfplotsset{height=5.0cm,width=7.0cm} % <---
    \input{Plot1.tex}
    \caption{Figure 1 caption.}
    \label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

where file `Plot1.tex` had to modified as follows:

```
%%%% Plot1.tex
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
%width=4.521in,             % <--- remove
%height=3.566in,            % <--- remove
%at={(0.758in,0.481in)},    % <--- remove, it has no sense
scale only axis,
bar width=0.8,
xmin=-0.2,
xmax=8.2,
xtick={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
xlabel={Case},
ymin=0,
ymax=4500,
ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
ylabel={Amount},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
]
\addplot[ybar stacked, fill=mycolor1, draw=black, area legend] table[row sep=crcr] {%
1   3364.193\\
2   2593.019\\
3   2636.492\\
4   2691.691\\
5   2792.946\\
6   2962.925\\
7   3109.8\\
};
\addplot[forget plot, color=white!15!black] table[row sep=crcr] {%
-0.2    0\\
8.2 0\\
};
\addlegendentry{Part 1}

\addplot[ybar stacked, fill=mycolor2, draw=black, area legend] table[row sep=crcr] {%
1   704.461\\
2   1275.311\\
3   1251.84\\
4   1196.23\\
5   1108.538\\
6   983.136\\
7   891.978\\
};
\addplot[forget plot, color=white!15!black] table[row sep=crcr] {%
-0.2    0\\
8.2 0\\
};
\addlegendentry{Part 2}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
```

Now the main file gives thew following result:

[image]

Now arise a question: since you need to edit all such files, isn't it simpler replace diagram's sizes (height, width) determined by Matlab with desired valuws (if they are different)?

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. I think it is possible that size is specified locally, see `Plot1.tex` contents in my updated question. However, it is my understanding that .tex files from matlab2tikz can in fact be scaled by using `figureheight` and `figurewidth`.

Comment: Than you not have `pgfplots` image. ah, you have locally defined image size. Remove this sizes from generated code.

Comment: Removing the locally defined sizes did work in combination with `pgfplotsset`. Thank you! Interestingly, it did not work in combination with `\setlength\figureheight` and `\setlength\figurewidth`, which was my initial approach.

Comment: Thank you for your updated answer. That solves my problem and also mentions the possibilities for specifying the size directly in `matlab2tikz` as discussed in the comments under the original question.